# Visual Studio: How to set Working Directory in Property Sheets?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

If I open up the Properties of any arbitrary project, I'm able to change the Working Directory of any target project:

[image: Working Directory]

However, if I try to open up an individual Property Sheet for a project, the "Debugging" Category is missing, and I cannot find any field I can alter which would allow me to set the Working Directory for that Property Sheet (which would therefore allow me to change the Working Directory for multiple projects simultaneously):

[image: Missing "Debugging" Category]

What can I do to change this property at a Property Sheet level?

Comment: I've been looking for an answer to this for over a decade. :(